# FILTRAR POR RANGOS DE FECHA EN UN DATATABLE PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, bootstrap, datatables

Espero que estén bien. Tengo un problema tengo una datatable que se va llenando automáticamente con datos de una base de datos, pero quisiera que se filtrara por rangos de fecha pero he buscado y no encuentro y lo que encuentro realmente no se si aplicara con lo que yo tengo.
Intente con una forma que encontre por internet pero veo que es para campos ya definidos pero como los traigo por base de datos no encontre manera de poder relacionarla.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<div class="filtro">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Inicio</label>
          <div><input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Fin</label>
          <div><input type="date" name="fecha_fin" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%" id="iddatatable">
        <thead style="background-color: #dc3545;color: white; font-weight: bold;">
            <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Documento</th>
            <th>Cama</th>
            <th>F. Solicitud</th>
            <th>Especialidad</th>
            <th>Prioridad</th>
            <th>Solicitud</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Opciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody >
        <tr>
        <?php 
             while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){?>
                <td><?php echo $ver[0] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[1]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[2]?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[3] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[4] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[5] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[6] ?></td>
```

No colocare todo el codigo del datatable debido a que tengo unas validaciones en unos campos y haria mas extenso el codigo y nada tiene que ver eso.
Ahora sigue el script para el datatable.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#iddatatable').DataTable({
            

            
            order: [[3, 'desc']],
            responsive:true,
            pageLength: 50,
        language: {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast":"Último",
                    "sNext":"Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                 },
                 "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
            },
        //para usar los botones   
        
        dom: 'Bfrtilp',       
        buttons:[ 
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                className: 'btn btn-success'
            },
            {
                extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger'
            },
            {
                extend:    'print',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
                className: 'btn btn-info'
            },
        ]           
    });     
});
</script>
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: no veo el codigo de la llamada a la base, el filtro que debes hacer es en la query y lo que debes enviar al php es el rango de fechas entre las que deseas buscar, eso se hace con 2 input de fecha inicio y fecha final, los datos los envias al php que te procesa los resultados de la tabla y alli re100 filtras para el resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la consulta debes poner la condición:

```
"SELECT * FROM mi_tabla WHERE campo_fecha BETWEEN dato1 AND dato2"
```

Y en el script donde declaras la DataTable:

```
var tabla = $('#example').DataTable({
                aaSorting: []
             });
```

Lo que hace "aaSorting: []" en resumen es que establece un arreglo vacío que deshabilita el ordenado automático

Comment: Parcero, muchas gracias. Me ayudaste mucho!